# What is the meaning of "reeling in the mastermind'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I saw this this expression in Full Metal Alchemist Brotherhood.

[image: full metal alchemist]

Comment: Can you provide a couple of surrounding sentences as context, please?

Comment: I have not seen it, but guess that someone has been assigned a job and is doing it badly, so "mastermind" is facetious. "Reeling in" is what you do to land a fish, so that is figurative.

Answer (score 1):

"reeling in" her means "capture" or possibly "trap". It suggests this will be achieved through a somewhat drawn-out process. The term is often used in connection with a police investigation that is not simple. It is, as Weather Vane's comment suggests, a metaphorical usage derived from fishing.

"The mastermind" might mean "the person planning and directing a group" usually a criminal or opposition group. Or it might be used ironically, as the comment suggests. Without context, there is no way to be sure, but I see no reason to assume irony, and would assume the straightforward meaning.